# NSLog minutes and seconds of NSDateComponents - How to display leading zeros?

Tags: ios, xcode

I really need help. The code result is `2:0:0` while the format is set to `hh:mm:ss`. I want the result to be `2:00:00` (adding `0` in front of the minutes and seconds when they are under `10`).

```
NSDateFormatter *test = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[test setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date1 = [test dateFromString:@"18:00:00"];
NSDate *date2 = [test dateFromString:@"20:00:00"];
NSCalendar* gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
unsigned int uintFlags =  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* differenceComponents = [gregorian components:uintFlags fromDate:date1 toDate:date2 options:0];

NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d",[differenceComponents hour],[differenceComponents minute],[differenceComponents second]);
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log using the `%02ld` specifier, for example:

```
NSLog(@"%ld:%02ld:%02ld",[differenceComponents hour],[differenceComponents minute],[differenceComponents second]);
```

Output:

```
2:00:00
```

Additionally create `NSStrings` like this:

```
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld:%02ld",[differenceComponents hour],[differenceComponents minute],[differenceComponents second]];
NSLog(@"%@",theString);
```

Comment: Damn i was soooo confused..  Thanks YOU!! :*

Comment: You may wish to elaborate on what exactly `%02ld` does, in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is: 00-00 is 0.
I used to have the problem and solved it like this

```
-(NSString*)formatIntToString:(int)inInt{
if (inInt <10) {
    NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",inInt];
    return theString;
}
else {
    NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",inInt];
    return theString;
}}
```

Use it like this in your NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%@:%@:%@",[self formatIntToString:[differenceComponents hour]],[self formatIntToString:[differenceComponents minute]],[self formatIntToString:[differenceComponents second]]);
```